# transfer functions into classes and arrays

Tags: ruby, function

This is the code that I wanted to make use of the repeated code by placing it at another function and storing the variables to that other function. I am not really new at this function type so I really need Some help, thank you so much for helping me.

```rb
def main
    marks = 0

    puts "1. What does the == operator do?"
    puts "(a) calculates an arithmetic solution."
    puts "(c) checks for e"
    puts "Your answer: "

    begin
        answer = gets.chomp
    end while (answer != 'a' && answer != 'b' && answer != 'c' && answer != 'd')
    
    if answer == 'c'
        score += 1
        puts "Correct  " 
    else
        puts "Wrong  " 
    end
    
    puts "2. Which is NOT a C keyword?"
    puts "(a) when"
    puts "(b) const"
    puts "(c) unsigned"
    
    puts "Your answer: "
    
    begin
        answer = gets.chomp
    end while (answer != 'a' && answer != 'b' && answer != 'c' && answer != 'd')
    
    if answer == 'a'
        score += 1
        puts "Correct  "
    else
        puts "Wrong  "
    end
    
    puts "3. In function call, the actual parameters are separated by"
    puts "(a) semicolons"
    puts "(b) colons"
    puts "(c) commas"
    puts "Your answer: "

    note

    
        answer = gets.chomp
    if answer != 'a' && answer != 'b' && answer != 'c' && answer != 'd'
    
    if answer == 'c'
        score += 1
        puts "Correct  " 
    else
        puts "Wrong  " 
    end
    
end  

main
```

Comment: You don;t want function - you want objects. You'd probably want to have Question objects (responsible for keeping your question data - question, itself, answers and which one is correct, later you could add special scoring logic and various types of questions), Quiz object (holding an array of questions) and QuizAttempt (referencing quiz, selected answers and final score) as your data layer. Then, simple QuizRunner object to act as console interface to loop over the quiz questions and build QuizAttempt.

Comment: could you teach me how to do it

Comment: @BroiSatse: that's quite a jump, though. Better to go with baby steps: extract a couple of DRY methods first.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I agree this is a massive leap, but one that (IMO) needs to be taken. From my experience, devs in training are very reluctant to make this jump, which only fixates them in procedural programming. OO is a different type of skill to langauge itself and/or algorithmic thinking and can be taught even if someone does not know how to code at all - I run occasional workshops in primary schools and kids just love drawing out "what talks to what" diagrams :)

Answer (score 1):

this isn't an easy step but, as per @BroiSatse's comments, creating the different aspects of the object as classes:

**Defining an object to hold possible answers**

```
class Answer
  attr_accessor :text, :correct
  def initialize text, correct
    @text = text
    @correct = correct
  end
end
```

**Defining an object to hold questions, which will contain an array of possible answers**

```
class Question
  attr_accessor :text, :answers
  def initialize text
    @text = text
    @answers = []
  end
end
```

**Defining the "Quiz" class, which contains the score, and an array of questions.  it also includes a routine to loop through the questions and answers stored in the quiz**

```
class Quiz
  attr_accessor :questions, :score
  def initialize
    @questions = []
    @score = 0
  end

  def ask_questions
    @questions.each_with_index do |question, i|
      puts "#{i+1}. #{question.text}"

      question.answers.each_with_index do |answer,i|
        a_letter = (i + 'a'.ord).chr
        puts "(#{a_letter}) #{answer.text}"
      end

      while true
        puts "Your answer: "
        user_answer = gets.chomp
        break if (user_answer&.ord - 'a'.ord)&.between?(0, question.answers.count-1)
      end

      if (question.answers[(user_answer.ord - 'a'.ord)]&.correct)
        @score += 1
        puts "Correct \tYour score is now " + @score.to_s
      else
        puts "Wrong \tYour score is still " + @score.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Use the new classes/objects**

Now that the classes are set up, we can create our "Quiz":

```
quiz=Quiz.new

question = Question.new("What does the == operator do?")
question.answers << Answer.new('calculates an arithmetic solution.', false)
question.answers << Answer.new('assigns a value to a variable.', false)
question.answers << Answer.new("checks for equality", true)
question.answers << Answer.new("draws the '=' character", false)
quiz.questions << question

question = Question.new("Which is NOT a C keyword?")
question.answers << Answer.new('when', true)
question.answers << Answer.new('const', false)
question.answers << Answer.new('unsigned', false)
question.answers << Answer.new('do', false)
quiz.questions << question

question = Question.new("In function call, the actual parameters are separated by")
question.answers << Answer.new('semicolons', false)
question.answers << Answer.new('colons', false)
question.answers << Answer.new('commas', true)
question.answers << Answer.new('space', false)
quiz.questions << question
```

**and finally run the "ask_questions" routine**

```
quiz.ask_questions
```

**demo output**

```
2.7.2 :124 > quiz.ask_questions
1. What does the == operator do?
(a) calculates an arithmetic solution.
(b) assigns a value to a variable.
(c) checks for equality
(d) draws the '=' character
Your answer:
c
Correct         Your score is now 1
2. Which is NOT a C keyword?
(a) when
(b) const
(c) unsigned
(d) do
Your answer:
c
Wrong   Your score is still 1
3. In function call, the actual parameters are separated by
(a) semicolons
(b) colons
(c) commas
(d) space
Your answer:
c
Correct         Your score is now 2
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but an answer isn't right or wrong by itself, it depends on the question. It might make more sense if the object holding the answers would know which of them is the correct one.

Comment: Mine allows for multiple possible correct answers, and for changing the order of the array elements on the fly ... But I take your point

Comment: You could reduce the code footprint a bit further by leveraging ruby's [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Struct.html).  Class definitions for `Question` and `Answer` can be replaced with the single lines `Question = Struct.new(:text, :answers)` and `Answer = Struct.new(:text, :correct)`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code is it alright or too sloppy

```
class Question
  attr_accessor :prompt, :answer
  def initialize(prompt, answer)
    @prompt = prompt
    @answer = answer
  end
end

p1 =
 "1. What does the == operator do?\n
 (c) checks for equality\n
 (d) draws the '=' character\n
 Your answer: \n"
p2 =
 "1. What does the == operator do?\n
 (b) assigns a value to a variable.\n
 (c) checks for equality\n
 (d) draws the '=' character\n
 Your answer: "
p3 =
"3.  the actual parameters are separated by\n

(b) colons\n
(c) commas\n


Your answer: "

questions = [
  Question.new(p1, "c"),
  Question.new(p2, "a"),
  Question.new(p3, "c"),
]

def run_test(questions)
answer = ""
score = 0
  for question in questions
    puts question.prompt
    
        answer = gets.chomp
    (answer != 'a' && answer != 'b' && answer != 'c' && answer != 'd')
    if answer == question.answer
      score += 1
      puts "Correct  " =
    else
      puts "Wrong  " 
    end
  end
end

run(questions)
```

Comment: It is much better! Your original code was extremely procedural and feature driven. In here you have some signs of OO - you have abstracted both the idea of Question, which now nicely encapsulates quiz data and the concept of runnign the quiz. Note now, that any change to the quiz itself does not require any changes to your run_test method - which is a massive maintanability boost. Additionally, your `run_test` makes just few assumptions about the `questions` - it only expects it to be an array of obejcts responding to `prompt` and `answer`. This is a great base to introduce polymoprhism later

Comment: However, let's make it even better. Firstly, it seems you're coming from C family background - we rarely use `for` and `while` loops in ruby. So instead of `for question in questions` do `questions.each do |question|` which is much more ruby-like. in this particular case `while` is used correctly, but you don't need `begin/end`: `answer = gets.chomp while asnwer != ...` woudl work as well. Since we're there - there is an important and dangerous assumption here - you assume that each question will have 4 answers. Try to correct that and make it more flexible.

Comment: All the question / answer data makes your code look more bloated that it actually is. It might be a good idea to separate data and code and move the questions into another file.